# How I can swap rows in ListView with drag and drop on Android?

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I want to swap rows in ListView.  Is there  any library or smth else for that?

Comment: [A complete example Demo is here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check [`Drag and drop list view on Android`](https://github.com/aleung/tasks365/blob/master/tasks365/src/leoliang/tasks365/DraggableListView.java)